# How to access shapes in Word form when protected?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word

I have a Word form that is protected. When I try to access a shape I get an error.

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Visible = False
```

[image: Popup error]

Comment: You need to unprotect the document first.

Comment: is there another solution?

Comment: No, there isn't. Look up `Unprotect` in the Object Browser and then see the online help.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I know that I have to unprotect the document, but I was just wondering if there's another solution

Comment: Solution is to let VBA unprotect it, do whatever you want to do and then let VBA protect it. Make sure you have an error handling that re-protects in a case of error. Otherwise it will remain unprotected whenever your VBA code throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an unprotected section in the document (it can be as little as a single paragraph mark), then drag the shape anchor to that section, you'll be able to access it with VBA.

But the code to unprotect and reprotect is pretty simple:

```
Sub HideShape()
    With ActiveDocument
        If .ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
            .Unprotect
        End If
        .Shapes("Rectangle 4").Visible = False
        .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
    End With
End Sub
```